# Captcha in JavaScript displaying the code in view source code

Tags: javascript, jsp, captcha

I have created a JSP page with captcha in JavaScript, but the problem is the script is viewable when I click "View source code" option by right clicking the JSP page. Even if I block the right click option, the code can be still viewable through "View source code" in Edit menu.

Any idea on how I can solve this problem? I am very new to JSP and servlets... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is executed on the client side, so it will **have** to be downloaded in the user's browser, there's no way to prevent that.

You can however have a look at [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) and/or [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation), but that will **not** prevent the user to see your script, it will just make it harder to read and understand.

As for Captchas, that's typically the kind of thing you want to handle server-side (in a servlet, for example), and not client-side (in JavaScript code).

Comment: how  about encrypting the particular jsp page??

Comment: JSP are compiled and executed server-side to produce HTML pages that will be sent client-side. Encrypting a JSP page, whatever you think that could mean, will not serve your purpose here...